# Dialog box Placement in Tkinter with Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a tkinter gui with python,but its not proper,When i click on Activate it should open a new box prompting user for Username and Pass,but there is some error;I have defined the problem below
Here is the code I am using:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from ttk import *
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top = Tk()

def helloCallBack():

top.title("Activation")

Label(top, text="Username").grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
Entry(top).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(top, text="Pass").grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
Entry(top).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Button(top, text="Submit").grid(row=2, column=1)

B = Tkinter.Button(text ="Activate", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
root.mainloop()
top.mainloop()
```

So the output that I'm getting is ;
[image]

And when i click on activate: 
[image: pic2]

Two problems here 
1.There is a blank box behind the root box when i run the program,how do i get rid of that?
2.The first message box(root) does not get deleted when i click on activate

Answer (score 2):

Your main mistake is two mainloops in your code (You trying to run two separate programms). Use `Toplevel()` widget instead of new instance of `Tk()` for your new box with username/pass pair and `destroy` method to close it.

So here's example:

```
from Tkinter import *


def show_form():
    root = Tk()
    b = Button(text="Activate", command=lambda: show_call_back(root))
    b.pack()
    root.mainloop()


def show_call_back(parent):
    top = Toplevel(parent)

    top.title("Activation")
    Label(top, text="Username").grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
    Entry(top).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)
    Label(top, text="Pass").grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
    Entry(top).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)
    Button(top, text="Submit", command=top.destroy).grid(row=2, column=1)

show_form()
```

In addition, [this](http://effbot.org) site is very recommened for you!

And some links:

[Toplevel widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

[Entry widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) (and how to grab strings from it and I think this is your next step)

Comment: @Lafexlos, I'm agree with you, thank you for addition! This is true and there's even more recommendations to OP like using *class-like* structure (smth like building your own `class App(tk.Tk)`) with methods and attributes to store this variables. But I assume that OP is new to python/tkinter and this info would be to complicated for him(or too straight so here's no room to own research, just copy/past). I just grabbed OP's code and made with it what he wanted.

Comment: Thank you ;) , yes i'm new to Python with Tkinter,so in the process of learning.